# Calculation of conditional probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I am taking an online course and I am not able to replicate the numbers the instructor displays during the course in this slide[image].

I am trying to figure out how the $P(d^1|g^3) \approx 0.63$ calculation was reached.

**EDIT**

Once I have calculated $P(d^1|g^3)$, how do I go about calculating $P(d^1|g^3, i^1)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, apply the Bayes Rule:$$p(d^1|g^3)=\frac{p(g^3|d^1)p(d^1)}{p(g^3)}$$
$p(d^1)$ is known. From the probability table, we know $p(g^3|i^m,d^n)$, and from total probability theorem we have: $$\begin{align}p(g^3|d^1)&=p(g^3|d^1,i^0)p(i^0)+p(g^3|d^1,i^1)p(i^1)\\&=0.7\times0.7+0.2\times 0.3=0.55\end{align}$$
$p(g^3)$ can also be found using total probability theorem as follows:
$$p(g^3)=p(g^3|d_1)p(d_1)+p(g^3|d_0)p(d_0)$$
Similarly, for $p(g^3|d_0)$, we have
$$\begin{align}p(g^3|d^0)&=p(g^3|d^0,i^0)p(i^0)+p(g^3|d^0,i^1)p(i^1)\\&=0.3\times0.7+0.02\times 0.3=0.216\end{align}$$
which yields $p(g^3)=0.55\times 0.4 + 0.216\times0.6=0.3496$, and $$p(d^1|g^3)=\frac{0.55\times0.4}{0.3496}\approx 0.63$$

Employ similar steps to reach $p(i^1|g^3)$.

Comment: Do you mind answering a followup question? I have added an edit section.

Comment: Use Bayes Rule again: $$(d^1|g^3,i^1)=\frac{p(g^3|d^1,i^1)p(d^1|i^1)}{p(g^3|i^1)}$$ $p(d^1|i^1)=p(d^1)$ since they're independent as shown in the BN. You can find $p(g^3|i^1)$ as proposed in the answers, and $p(g^3|d^1,i^1)$ is given in the table.